# IIS restart is required to get new data

Tags: iis, post, get, restart

Folks,

Steps to repro

1. HTML page makes a 'POST'action to a Web API to insert a record on a table.
2. Web API calls database and executes stored procedure
3. Data is insert into table correctly.
4. User reloads page (refresh page).
5. On refresh HTML page makes a new 'GET' action to Web API to get all records

Result

New record is not displayed.  Only when IIS is restarted is the new record displayed

Expected Result
All data to display without a need for a IIS restart

Comment: Do you cache data somewhere during call?

Comment: I don't cache any data during the call

Comment: here is the api call http://xxxxxxxxxx:xx/api/AccountTransactions?AccountId=1  the new transaction will only display when I restart IIS

Comment: Can you provide code for API method?

Comment: public IEnumerable<AccountTransaction> GetAccountsByAccountId(string accountId)
        {
            return repository.GetAll().Where(
                p => string.Equals(p.AccountId, accountId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

Comment: Check if repository has some caching included, it looks like that is problem.

Comment: The WebApi is caching a list of transactions and does not refresh from DB when a new GET request is made

thanks for point me in the right direction!!!